# I am getting an error. I need to create img tag

Tags: javascript

```
var courseImage = document.getElementsByClassName("coursebox");
imgCourse = document.createElement("img");
imgCourse.setAttribute("src", "http://google.com");
courseImage.appendChild(imgCourse);
```

I am geting Error `Uncaught TypeError: courseImage.appendChild is not a function`.

Please help

Comment: `courseImage` is a collection of elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code returns a `HTMLCollection`:

```
var courseImage = document.getElementsByClassName("coursebox");
```

So take the first element from the collection. Use it this way:

```
var courseImage = document.getElementsByClassName("coursebox")[0];
```

Your full code will now be:

```
var courseImage = document.getElementsByClassName("coursebox")[0];
imgCourse = document.createElement("img");
imgCourse.setAttribute("src", "http://google.com");
courseImage.appendChild(imgCourse);
```

Comment: thank you, how can i append  it to top of coursebox div any solution

Comment: There's no `.prependChild()` by default... So we need to create it. There's an excellent tutorial here. Ask me if you are stuck. [Prepend Child JavaScript](http://callmenick.com/post/prepend-child-javascript).